# AWS Glue Streaming Job could not connect to Kafka

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-kafka, aws-glue

I am trying to implement Glue ETL Job with self managed Kafka cluster (on EC2 instances). Cluster is working, as I checked with simple poducer and consumer scripts on my local machine.
The problem is that in Glue Job I get the following warning in logs:

```
Feb 11, 2021, 5:31:06 PM 21/02/11 11:31:06 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-3e37027f-1b50-4aac-bbbf-68c11f4db9bd-1062155183-driver-0] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Feb 11, 2021, 5:33:17 PM 21/02/11 11:33:17 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-3e37027f-1b50-4aac-bbbf-68c11f4db9bd-1062155183-driver-0] Connection to node -3 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Feb 11, 2021, 5:35:28 PM 21/02/11 11:35:28 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-3e37027f-1b50-4aac-bbbf-68c11f4db9bd-1062155183-driver-0] Connection to node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Feb 11, 2021, 5:37:39 PM 21/02/11 11:37:39 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-3e37027f-1b50-4aac-bbbf-68c11f4db9bd-1062155183-driver-0] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
Feb 11, 2021, 5:39:50 PM 21/02/11 11:39:50 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-3e37027f-1b50-4aac-bbbf-68c11f4db9bd-1062155183-driver-0] Connection to node -3 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I checked SGs for EC2 instances, settings of the connection in Glue, but it still is not working

Comment: Did you try to manually check your network level? That you have a good network connectivity and all the ports are open? Broker may be literally unavailable.

Comment: @OlegChirukhin yes, all brokers are working and connection is fine when I connect to them from my local machine. For testing purpose I used default Security Group on EC2 which just allows all traffic from/to anywhere

Comment: Do you use something like `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS>:9092` inside the `server.properties`?

btw, there's a good article about setting up listeners: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

AWS problems can be extremely difficult, anything can break anywhere, and I think this log file is not enough to trace the problem

You just said you can execute simple producer and consumer scripts on your local laptop, but do they work if you put them on the other AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes, I set `advertised.listeners` in every instance also `zookeper.connect`

Comment: But are the advertised addresses available for access from Glue? Sounds like you've only set them up for your local access